# Find a record with max value in a group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the next dataset:

```
|month|temperature|city|
|    1|  15.0     |foo |
|    1|  20.0     |bar |
|    2|  25.0     |baz |
|    2|  30.0     |quok|
```

I want to find cities with highest temperatures per month:

```
|month|temperature|city|
|    1|20.0       |bar |
|    2|30.0       |quok|
```

How to do this using apache spark SQL? I tried to use window functions but failed to get the right results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `window` function you can do it as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{max}

val l = Seq((1, 15.0, "foo"), (1, 20.0, "bar"), (2, 25.0, "baz"), (2, 30.0, "quok"))

val df = l.toDF("month", "temperature", "city")

val w = Window.partitionBy("month")

df.withColumn("m", max("temperature").over(w))
  .filter($"temperature" === $"m")
  .select("month", "temperature", "city")
  .show()

+-----+-----------+----+
|month|temperature|city|
+-----+-----------+----+
|    1|       20.0| bar|
|    2|       30.0|quok|
+-----+-----------+----+
```

Alternatively, you can do it also using `groupBy` + `join`:

```
val maxT = df.groupBy("month").agg(max("temperature").alias("maxT"))

df.join(maxT, Seq("month"), "left")
  .filter($"temperature" === $"maxT")
  .select("month", "temperature", "city")
  .show()

+-----+-----------+----+
|month|temperature|city|
+-----+-----------+----+
|    1|       20.0| bar|
|    2|       30.0|quok|
+-----+-----------+----+
```

What is more efficient depends on the data. If the aggregated DataFrame can be broadcasted, the join will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is probabely to put both `temperature` and `city` in a struct in combination with `max` aggregation:

```
val df = Seq((1, 15.0, "foo"), (1, 20.0, "bar"), (2, 25.0, "baz"), (2, 30.0, "quok")).toDF("month", "temperature", "city")


df
  .groupBy($"month")
  .agg(max(struct($"temperature",$"city")).as("maxtemp"))
  .select($"month",$"maxtemp.*")
  .show()
```

gives :

```
+-----+-----------+----+
|month|temperature|city|
+-----+-----------+----+
|    1|       20.0| bar|
|    2|       30.0|quok|
+-----+-----------+----+
```

Comment: With this approach, only one city per month will satisfy the `max` checking.  For example, if both `foo` and `bar` had temperature 20.0 for month `1`, only `foo` would be in the result as `(20.0, "foo") > (20.0, "bar")`.

Comment: @Leo C true, did not thought about that as it did not appear in the test case and its also not indicated in the title